# How do you change the page layout?

Tags: facebook

I somehow accidentally changed my page layout.  Now there is a lot of blank space to the left and everything else is smaller.  HOW DO I CHANGE IT BACK?  This should be easy to find the answer to but nothing ever is on Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **page**:

1. Find "**Settings**" (top right, for me) and click it
2. On left sidebar, find "**Templates and Tabs**", and click it
3. On right panel, your "**current template**" (refers to your page design) will be shown (either *movies, business, venues, nonprofit, politicians, services, cafes, etc*.)
4. Underneath your "current template", default (or current) **tabs** are shown.

Template and tabs are all adjustable here in this panel, on the right side for most U.S. users on desktop.